# GCC compiler Windows questions

Tags: c++, gcc, windows-7, cilk-plus

1. Is it dangerous to install GCC 4.7 if you already have 4.4.1 installed? If so, how do I uninstall the obsolete version?
2. Where can I download the newest, **free**, **Windows-compatible**, **Cilk+ containing** GCC version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first quest the answer is No. Just select in your IDE the right tool chain. For the second question see [Download Intel® Cilk++ SDK](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/download-intel-cilk-sdk).

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded cilk-8503-x86-64.release.tar but I just see a bunch of files inside. How can I install it? Or which IDE do you recommend in which I can set some directory setting to reference those files for compilation?

Comment: nevermind, they have an installer